# Is "to be confused about A with B" correct grammatically?

Tags: passive-voice, transitivity

I know we can use **confuse A with B** to mean **to mistake A for B**, but I would like to use the passive voice.

Is the following sentence correct grammatically (and/or idiomatic)?

> I was confused about the concept with another one.

Comment: Hi technophyle! Do you want to edit your question and tell us why you want to make a passive construction? We usually make passive constructions when we have an action (like *confuse*) and the person or thing performing the action is not the subject of a sentence. This becomes complicated because *confuse* can be a stative verb, not always descriptive of an action.

Comment: My first thought was the "passive" form would be *A was confused with B* (or *B was confused with A*). But that's not really right. I don't think there actually *is* a single-word English verb meaning *to **mutually** misclassify two things* that can be "passivized" in this way, so the best I can come up with is *A and B were **mistaken for each other*** (or *...each mistaken for the other*).

Answer (score 1):

> *I was confused about the concept with another one.*

I won't downvote your question, but I would downvote that sentence. However, you could say:

> *I was confused about the two concepts*.

Here's the problem with the original: You can't use the *X with Y* construct as the object the prepositional phrase beginning with *about* (at least, you can't do so in this particular context).

Comment: Another way to express it would be *A and B was confusing to me*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer J.R. But what I would like to say is I mistook A for B, not A and B.

Comment: If that's what you want to say, then that's what you should say: _I mistook A for B_ (or, perhaps, _I confused A with B_). But that's not what you originally asked about here.

Answer (score 0):

"I was confused about the concept with another one"-The stress goes on the user that he is confused about something and listener is not made sure on which he is confused. So it would be perfect to use " I was confused about the given concept with another one.